# @PostMapping with multiple RequestParams

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, spring-boot, post

I have a spring boot rest controller with a post method. I want to pass multiple parameters to the method from JavaScript post method. I'm passing my post method data as follows..

```
    {
      productPrices: {
                     fromDate: "2019-01-01",
                     toDate: "2019-02-01",
                     purchasePrice: "100",
                     retailPrice: "200",
                     wholesalePrice: "300"
                   },
                    pricesList : JSON.stringify(dataArr)
}
```

My Rest Controller is like this.

```
@RestController
public class ProductRestController {

    @PostMapping("/addPrdPriceData")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> addToCart(@NonNull @RequestParam(name = "productPrices") ProductPrices productPrices, @RequestParam(name = "pricesList") List<ProductPrices> pricesList) {

 }
}
```

When I call the Post method I'm getting following error.

```
> [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required ProductPrices parameter 'productPrices' is not present]
```

what did I do wrong here?????

Comment: You are passing JSON not separate request parameters.

Comment: `what did I do wrong here?????` : You didn't red the spring documentation.

Comment: With JSON is there a way to do this?@M. Deinum

Comment: Checkout the difference between queryparam and request body. Do check out `@RequestBody` annotation as well

Comment: Your request body is also weird, why the value of `pricesList` is `JSON.stringify(dataArr)`? I think it is just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing data as a single entity, use single request parameter.

js.

```
 {
  "productData"
      {
        "productPrices": {
         "fromDate": "2019-01-01",
         "toDate": "2019-02-01",
         "purchasePrice": "100",
         "retailPrice": "200",
         "wholesalePrice": "300"
       },
        "pricesList" : JSON.stringify(dataArr)
       }
 }
```

Java

```
public class ProductRestController {

  @PostMapping("/addPrdPriceData")
  @ResponseBody
  public Map<String, Object> addToCart(@NonNull @RequestBody
  ProductData productData) {

  }
  }
```